# Not commiting after swap within a Collection with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, collections

Working with hibernate 4.1.7, I have a class with a Collection (attachments), defined in the mapping file as:

```
<list lazy="false" table="news_attachment" name="attachments">
      <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
      <key column="news"/>
      <index column="index_attachment"/>
      <many-to-many class="mypackage.Archive" column="attachment" unique="true"/>
</list>
```

I am trying to swap two elements with:

```
   Archive archive0 = news.getAttachments().get(0);
   Archive archive1 = news.getAttachments().get(1);
   news.getAttachments().set(0, archive1);
   news.getAttachments().set(1, archive0);
```

But, in commit time, I get an awful

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '163703' for key 'attachment'
```

And, for my surprise, mysql updates are:

```
          479 Query     update news_attachment set attachment=163703 where news=53306 and index_attachment=0
          479 Query     update news_attachment set attachment=163703 where news=53306 and index_attachment=0
```

(the surprise is id and index are always the same).

But, if I create a new List, set the objects in the new order and execute the setter, everything works fine.

```
List<Archive> list = new ArrayList<Archive>();
list.add(news.getAttachments().get(1));
list.add(news.getAttachments().get(0));
news.setAttachments(list);
```

mysql.log outputs the inserts as I expected, different ids and indexes.

Are operations on the original list, not recommended?